# Create an pd.Dataframe from series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Dataframe like this:
[image]

then i am going to get one row with this and add a new column with an column Name time and value 15.

```
loc_OBL_ein = df.loc[5]
loc_OBL_ein.insert(1,'time',value=15)
```

then i get an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'insert'.
My idea now was to convert loc_OBL_ein into an object with the same column names like df. How can I do that?
Or is there another way to get this one particular row and keep the object format?

Thank you,
R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need nested lists to get the row in the `DataFrame` from index 5:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

loc_OBL_ein = df.loc[[5]]
loc_OBL_ein.insert(1,'time',value=15) 
print (loc_OBL_ein)
   A  time  B  C  D  E  F
5  f    15  4  3  0  4  b
```

Comment: the difference between loc_OBL_ein = df.loc[5] and loc_OBL_ein = df.loc[[5]] is that if I use two [[]] i get a nested list? @jezrael

Comment: @raffa_sa - yes, if select by `[]` it returned `Series`, if select by `[[]]` it returned `DataFrame`. Also if need multiple rows use `[[4,5]]`

Comment: thank you - i don't know how but you always got the right answers to my questions  :)